# How to check updated value after a simulated change event in React enzyme?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to check the updated value of an input field after a simulated change event.

```
const wrapper = mount(<input type="number" value="hello" onChange="onChangeFunc"/>);
wrapper.simulate('change', {target: {value: "2"}});
expect(wrapper.props().value).to.equal('3');
```

Any idea why this is not working? I'm thinking setState is asynchronous and it might take place after the test has returned.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have input type="number" and you are entering text, second you are not handling onChange event, this is where your input value should update. look at code below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)} />
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

and then in test do like that

```
describe("Test", () => {

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Test />
    );

    it("should enter valid value", () => {
      wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {target: {value: "hello!"}});
      expect(wrapper.find('input').props().value).to.equal('hello!');
      console.log(wrapper.find('input').props().value);
    });


  });
```

Comment: Actually my original code has a change function and a number value.. I was writing up an example on top of my head. Thanks for the correction.